# Applet not reading file

Tags: java, file, applet

I have an applet that I am trying to make read a file. It throws an exception, but I am passing it the correct path so I am not sure where I am going wrong. I am using this to read numbers and use those numbers to change a multidimensional array, if you were wondering. Heres the code:

```
public class Save {
    public void loadSave(File loadPath) {
        try {
            Scanner loadScanner = new Scanner(loadPath);

            while(loadScanner.hasNext()){
                for(int y = 0; y < Screen.room.block.length;y++){
                    for(int x = 0; x < Screen.room.block[0].length;x++){
                        Screen.room.block[y][x].groundID = loadScanner.nextInt();
                        System.out.println(loadScanner.nextInt());
                    }   
                }
                for(int y = 0; y < Screen.room.block.length;y++){
                    for(int x = 0; x < Screen.room.block[0].length;x++){
                        Screen.room.block[y][x].airID = loadScanner.nextInt();
                    }   
                }
            }
            loadScanner.close();
        } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

How I access it:

```
    save.loadSave(new File(frame.getClass().getResource("mission1.tdm").toString()));
```

Ok, I used the edited code up above and it still says that it cannot find the file, even though the error spits out the exact path that it is in.

Comment: What is the exact exception thrown and error message? Where is the file located? Does your applet have the correct security permissions to access it?

Comment: error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: mission1.tdm (The system cannot find the file specified)   The file is also located in the src folder of my project, so it should have no security restrictions

Comment: A sand-boxed applet will not be allowed to read files.  If sand-boxed it will need to access the resource by URL relative to the code base, document base or class-path.

Comment: *"The file is also located in the src folder of my project, so it should have no security restrictions"*  That is irrelevant. It seems your IDE is running the applet with no security manager.

Comment: How would I do that? also, I have loaded images in it, is that any different permission-wise or not?

Comment: This might be useful as an alternative: http://stackoverflow.com/q/574675/422353

Comment: 1) Add @Code-Guru (or whoever) to notify them of new comments. 2) This files sounds like an 'application resource' so it will end up in the Jar.  Access it as it it were an [embedded-resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) and it should be loadable by a sand-boxed app.

Comment: Ok, look I am pretty decent with Java, but when it comes to the io.File class I am pretty nooby. Would you mind posting a full answer that explains this in detail?

Comment: @user1871085  *"Would you mind posting a full answer that explains this in detail?"*   <DWS>Would you mind paying me to do this ***yet again*** especially for you?</DWS>

Comment: I am not trying to be obnoxious, I am really thankful that you are helping me so I will use the resources you gave me in the embedded-resource link and you dont have to help anymore if you dont want. I am just trying to fully understand and learn something.

Comment: I am using a Scanner to load the file, the link you supplied me with doesnt go over scanners